# How to get date from time() value stored in DB

Tags: php, date

I am storing time of record creation as time(); in database. But How can I get the date from the same value ...ie when record was created.

Comment: So, you want to convert a timestamp in a date?

Comment: database? which database mySQL, mssql? ....

Comment: Have you tried any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the php [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function to convert a timestamp to a date.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use date() function

```
<?php
   $t=time();
   echo($t . "<br>");
   echo(date("Y-m-d",$t));
 ?>
```

OR
If you are using mysql

```
 mysql> select  from_unixtime(yourtimefield, '%Y %D %M') from yourtable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current date using a pre-made mysql function

```
SELECT CURDATE();
```

This will give you the current date where the MySQL server is running to.

Answer (score 0):

please use any of one below coding

### Mysql

- CURRENT_DATE();
- NOW();

### Php

$date = ('Y-m-d H:i:s');